# How to use filter selector

Tags: jquery

Here's my problem.
I'd like to filter this table to show all Status "Active".
I use this code, but the result is only on the visible rows (x3) and not on the all base.
I think this code needs to be changed.

**var trs = $('tr:not(:first)');**

[Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncUCJ.jpg)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio[name="type_affect"]').change(function () {
        var status = $('input[name="status"]:checked').prop('value');
        **var trs = $('tr:not(:first)');**
        $(trs).hide();
          if(status != ''&& status != 'none'){
              var chkdName = $('input[name="status"]:checked').prop('name');
              trs = $(trs).find("."+chkdName+':contains('+status+')').parent();
          }
        $(trs).show();
    });
    $("#reset").on('click', function(){
      $(':radio').prop('checked', false);
      $('tr').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: There's no logic in your selector which takes into consideration active vs. non-active; it merely selectors all rows except the first.

Comment: Yes, I know! I can't find the code to display everything. That's my question.

Comment: Well you don't show us your HTML structure. And your JS demonstrates a reasonable knowledge of JavaScript and selectors, so it's strange that you can't even attempt a selector to target non-active rows. If they have a class or something, just target that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply a moment of weakness!

I changed everything and here my solution.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio[name="status"]').change(function () {
    var filtering = FooTable.get('#tab-search').use(FooTable.Filtering);
        var filter = $(this).val();
    if (filter === 'none') {
        filtering.removeFilter('status');
    } else {
        filtering.addFilter('status', filter, ['status']);
    }
    filtering.filter();
    });
});
```